# How do I know a numbered equation is called later or not?

Tags: equations, labels

I am using amsart package to write my thesis. I use command like

```
\begin{equation}\label{...}
...
\end{equation}
```

to write my equation, and hence all equations are numbered and labeled.

There are like more than 300s equations in my thesis now...

However, my advisor ask me only number and label the equation if you will call it later. So, I am wondering that is there a way that I can know whether I called a labeled equation in my thesis or not? I don't want to check them one by one... tooooo time consuming...

Thank you!

Comment: Package `refcheck` might help here

Comment: With the `mathtools` package, which extends `amsmath`, you can use `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}`.